# MOVING TO ORACLE 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, migration, oracle-12c, rman

I have an rman backup of 11.2.0.2. Also I have installed 12c on a separate server. Can I move my backup to 12c. if yes?
Please guide me how to do it?
Appreciate your comments and answer.

Answer (score 3):

Restore the database as you would normally do it.

But at the end, instead of:

```
alter database open resetlogs;
```

Open the database with:

```
alter database open resetlogs upgrade;
```

Then upgrade the database to the new release. Instructions can be found at:

[Manually Upgrading a Non-CDB Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/upgrade.htm#CHDBHAHE)

Note that the above documentation is for version 12.1.

Direct upgrade from 11.2.0.2 to 12.2 is not supported, you need an extra upgrade step to 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4 or 12.1 before upgrading to 12.2.

Comment: I hv installed 12.1.0.2.0, So direct upgrade is possible?

Comment: @RahmanGurbaz 12.1 upgrade guide: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/intro.htm - *You may perform a direct upgrade to Oracle Database 12c if your current Oracle Database is release 10.2.0.5, 11.1.0.7, or release 11.2.0.2 or later.*